# Editing EXIF populated fields - HOW?

Tags: views

I am using Drupal 7. I have created a content type IMAGE with keywords, caption, headline, category populated by EXIF and I also autogenerate the label. All I have to do is select a local image and hit save and everything I need is populated from the image metadata - all good so far.

The only problem is that I cannot edit the EXIF populated fields. If  I want to move an image from one category (taxonomy) to another or notice a typo in the caption the only way I can make corrections is to delete the image, correct the text locally and reupload the image - when I select EDIT having found the content the default edit page does not show the field populated by EXIF. If I change them on the content type to a text or taxonomy field I can edit them, but I can't do that each time I want to edit a field.

I have searched but found nothing to help. Alternatively I have considered duplicating the EXIF populated fields on the IMAGE content type amd populating them using tokens from the EXIF populated fields and using those to drive my display views etc. I should then be able to edit them but it is not a very elegant solutions. *(I am not sure that will work after initially trying it)*

I also have an issue that I need a multi-valued field other than keywords that I can use for the category/gallery (and there isn't one in the standard it seems). That will probably be a separate question when I have solved the editing problem.

*Since initially posing the question I tried using EditableViews modules which looked promising but it would still not let me edit the fields (editable version) although it did display them.*